# Logging via TraceSource in Xamarin (UWP)

Tags: xamarin, uwp, tracelistener

I just want to log to console and to a log file, using a standard TraceSource, in my Xamarin app that will run on UWP, Mac OS X, iOS and Android. I'm developing/debugging on UWP.

TraceSource, TraceListener, and TextWriterTraceListener are indeed all available in .Net Standard library, so perhaps I'm setting it up incorrectly? Most places on the Internet insist on setting up trace listeners in an app.config file, but this is not applicable nor possible for Xamarin apps. So here is my logging initialization code, mostly based on an example in Microsoft docs:

```
        private void SetupLogging()
        {
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out, "consoleTraceListener"));
            string logFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "Application.log");
            if (!File.Exists(logFilePath)) File.Create(logFilePath);

            var logFileTraceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(logFilePath, "logFileTraceListener");
            Trace.Listeners.Add(logFileTraceListener);

            Trace.Write("Test");
            Trace.TraceInformation("Logging Initialized. Log file location: " + logFilePath);
            Trace.Flush();
        }
```

When I run this in a Xamarin UWP app, a file is created but nothing is written to it, nor can I find anything in the Output of the program (there is no `ConsoleTraceListener` so I'm trying to write a `TextWriterTraceListener` to `Console.Out`). Can someone provide a working example for Xamarin? (I haven't tried the Android or iOS apps yet; want to get UWP on the local machine working first.)

Comment: Does the following answer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you passed wrong string parameter to [`TextWriterTraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_TextWriterTraceListener__ctor_System_String_System_String_) method. Please try to pass `Stream` parameter. You could use following code directly. by the way, you'd better use `LocalApplicationData` SpecialFolder that could be accessed successfully within uwp.

```
private void SetupLogging()
{
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out, "consoleTraceListener"));
    string logFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Application.log");
    if (!File.Exists(logFilePath))
    {
        File.Create(logFilePath);
    }
    var logFileTraceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(File.Open(logFilePath,FileMode.Open), "logFileTraceListener");
    Trace.Listeners.Add(logFileTraceListener);

    Trace.Write("Test");
    Trace.TraceInformation("Logging Initialized. Log file location: " + logFilePath);
    Trace.Flush();
}
```

Comment: In my android app I would like to listen to the TracseSource events emitted by a 3rd Party Package , I have detailed my question in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970153/how-to-listen-to-tracesource-events-in-xamarin-application-project can you check and help me how to write TraceSource Events in a log file

Comment: I afraid I could not answer the third part library case, and for more communities will view your question, please add xamarin-anroid tag.